# Normalizer proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a,x\in G$ show that $N(xax^{-1}) = xN(a)x^{-1}$?

I know that $N(a)$ is the set of all elements of G that commute with a. Thus I can get $N(a) = N(xax^{-1})$ so $N(xax^{-1})$ is also the set of all elements of G that commute with a, but how do I get $xN(a)x^{-1} = N(xax^{-1})$?

Comment: This can be seen as a special case of the fact that stabilizers of elements in a given orbit are conjugate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N(a) = \{y \in G : ya = ay\}$, so if $b = xax^{-1}$, you want to show that
$$
y\in N(a) \Leftrightarrow xyx^{-1} \in N(b)
$$
Now
$$
y \in N(a) \Leftrightarrow yay^{-1} = a 
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow xyay^{-1}x^{-1} = xax^{-1}
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow xyx^{-1}\cdot xax^{-1}\cdot xy^{-1}x^{-1} = b
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow xyx^{-1}\cdot b \cdot (xyx^{-1})^{-1} = b
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow xyx^{-1} \in N(b)
$$

Comment: I would've never seen that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Prahlad, I was going over your answer and something confused me. Why exactly do we have to show $y\in N(a) \Leftrightarrow xyx^{-1} \in N(b)$ and why did we introduce two new variables?

Comment: I introduced $b$ just to make things look a little simpler. The $y$ is merely an arbitrary element in $N(a)$.